# How to write regular expression for getting text which is not in double quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have following text and pattern.

```js
var str = 'Give 13234 "100" "1.2.3.4"  %!'; 
var patt1 = /"(.*?)"/gm;
var result = str.match(patt1);
```

Result gives me the text which is in double quotes :
`"100","1.2.3.4"`

Is there any query which will give me the text which is not in double quotes?

Expected result is : `Give 13234 %!`

Comment: Use `.replace` with your regex to remove the matched texts from your string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a non greedy quantifier `.*?` you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `"[^"]*" *` to match the double quotes followed by 0+ spaces and replace that with an empty string.

If you don't want to match newline you can add the to the character class `"[^\n"]*"`

```js
var str = 'Give 13234 "100" "1.2.3.4" %!';
var patt1 = /"[^"]*" */gm;
var result = str.replace(patt1, "");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is in line what I suggested, +1. BTW, it is not always clear what OP wants to do with whitespace, you chose to remove the trailing one. I prefer to split and then join strings in such scenarios, something like `str.split(/\s*"[^"]*"\s*/).filter(Boolean).join(' ')`. Then, you can adjust the spacing between the split elements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good advice, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regexpr:

`/".*?"|([^"]*)/g` in group 1 we have the items looked for. Take into account that this regexpr will provide isolated `spaces`

```js
const regex = /".*?"|([^"]*)/g;
const str = `Give 13234 "100" "1.2.3.4" %!`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        groupIndex === 1 && match && console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I believe you aimed at `str.replace(/\s*".*?"\s*|([^"])/g, "$1")`

Answer (score -1):

Definitely it's not a good practice to write regex like `(.*?)` , because you are matching anything.

I think this example is more cleaner:

```
var str = 'Give 13234 "100" "1.2.3.4"  %!'; 
str.replace(/\s?"(.*?)"\s?/g,'');
```

and for the current case I would change the regex to:

```
/\s?"(\d+\.?){1,4}"\s?/g

optional match space
(match one or more digits and optional match dot){match the right side from 1 to 4 times}
optional match space
```

Comment: This `.replace(/\s?"(.*?)"\s?/g,'')` is fragile since you risk "gluing" words.